# Mongoose - Using variables in find methods returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an issue when attempting to use the find methods in mongoose when searching for an object.

When I do this:

```
var newObj = MyObject();

newObj.save(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;       
});

MyObject.findOne({ _id: newObj._id }, function(err, obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

null is returned. However, if say for "_id" a value is used like so:

```
....({ _id: 'abc1233dff4f24f' }....
```

then the object is returned. Any ideas why this might be happening? It seems like anytime any variable is used, the returned value is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to believe the `save` has completed before you try to find the object.  You should do the find inside the callback:

```
newObj.save(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;  
    MyObject.findOne({ _id: newObj._id }, function(err, obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    });     
});
```